# How to construct the map relating topological and algebraic $K$ - theory ?.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, topological-k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

Let $X$ be a complex projective variety, and let $ X^{an} $ denote the topological space of complex points of $ X $ equipped with the analytic topology. Then, any algebraic vector bundle $ E \to X $ determines a topological vector bundle $ E^{an} \to X^{an} $.

How to construct a natural map $ K_0 (X) \to K_{top}^{0} (X^{an} ) $ such that : $ CH^* (X) \otimes \mathbb{Q} \simeq K_0 (X) \otimes \mathbb{Q} \to K_{top}^0 (X^{an} ) \otimes \mathbb{Q} \simeq H^{ev} ( X^{an} , \mathbb{Q} ) $ ?.

$ K_{top}^0 ( X^{an} ) $ is the Grothendieck group of topological vector bundles over $ X^{an} $.

$ K_0 (X) $ is the Grothendieck group of algebraic vector bundles over $X$.

Could you tell me furthermore why do we have : $ CH^* (X) \otimes \mathbb{Q} \simeq K_0 (X) \otimes \mathbb{Q} $ ( ring isomorphism ) and $ K_{top}^0 (X^{an} ) \otimes \mathbb{Q} \simeq H^{ev} ( X^{an} , \mathbb{Q} ) $ ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't have much time at the moment, but this is in Atiyah–Hirzebruch, "[The Riemann–Roch theorem for analytic embeddings](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0040-9383(65)90023-6)," see Thm. 4.2. For the non-singular analogue, you would want to look at Baum–Fulton–MacPherson, "[Riemann–Roch and topological *K*-theory for singular varieties](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02392091)," §4.